# How to obtain SQL Server query text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Hibernate running queries.

I'm lazy and want to see the SQL it generates, steal it, and use it later (instead of writing it myself).

There are multiple queries being run.

I know I can do something like

```
INSERT INTO my_sql_text_table
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
    req.session_id,
    req.status,
    req.command,
    req.cpu_time,
    req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

to get the currently running SQL.

What's the easiest way to grab all running SQL for a short period of time so I can replay it?
Limiting to a table or a few tables is OK, so I'm cool with a trigger or something that can do it.

Comment: If I run your query without the insert I get THIS query in TEXT. Is this intended?

Comment: Meh, it's irrelevant really.  I wouldn't need this query's text (because I obviously already have it), but it doesn't bother me that it's there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) if you want to seee the query fired by code....

Comment: Ah dude, that's definitely the right answer!  Totally forgot profiler existed! (it's been like a year since I'd done any SQL work).  Now I feel stupid... But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the nhibernate show_sql property to true or set the NHibernate.SQL logger to DEBUG level.

[See the NH wiki for details](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx)